# PathFileExistsA fails for UTF-8?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, utf-8

I'm working with VS2017 and need to support UTF-8 paths due to an SDK that only supports UTF-8. Within my code, I'd like to test whether a UTF-8 path is valid, so am using

```
PathFileExistsA( path );
```

but it fails for a path I know is valid. (It passes if "path" has only ascii characters -- no chars requiring UTF-8).

I realized the "A" in PathFileExistsA stands for Ascii, but that's at the exclusion of UTF-8? Its counterpart is PathFileExistsW, but I can't use wide chars.

All I'm after is a test to determine whether a UTF-8 path is valid, so can use another function if more suitable.

Comment: Windows doesn't really support UTF-8 natively. What led you to believe it did?

Comment: "*I realized the "A" in PathFileExistsA stands for Ascii*" - no, it stands for ANSI. Win32 "A" functions expect data to be in the user's current locale, not in UTF-8. "*Its counterpart is PathFileExistsW, but I can't use wide chars*" - yes, you can, and should. Win32 "W" functions work with UTF-16, and converting between UTFs is lossless.

Comment: @Remy, thanks for the info about UTF-8. Super helpful. Regarding wide chars, of course I can use them in my app but I can't pass them to the SDK I'm using because it doesn't support them. It only supports UTF-8.

Comment: @buttonsrtoys which is fine. Like I said, you can convert between UTF-8 and UTF-16 when needed, without losing any data. It is just a fact of life on Windows that the Win32 API supports UTF-16 but not UTF-8. You have to work around that.

Answer (score 2):

Windows natively uses UTF-16 (wide chars) for its APIs.  If you can't use wide chars for your input, then you can accept it as UTF-8 and convert it to wide chars using `MultiByteToWideChar()` and then call the wide char version of the API function:

```
char* lpUtf8 = ...;
// Look up the size of the wide string
size_t wideSize = ::MultiByteToWideChar( CP_UTF8, 0, lpUtf8, -1, 0, 0 );
// Allocate the string
wchar_t* lpWideString = new wchar_t[wideSize];
// Do the conversion
::MultiByteToWideChar( CP_UTF8, 0, lpUtf8, -1, lpWideString, wideSize );
// Call the wide function
::PathFileExistsW( lpWideString );
// Deallocate the string
delete[] lpWideString;
```

It's much cleaner if you use the STL string functions.  This article is very good:

[C++ - Unicode Encoding Conversions with STL Strings and Win32 APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt763237.aspx)